# How to disable buttons while server handles a request in RoR/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a page that is generated using RoR, JQuery and Bootstrap.

that page has three action buttons: `edit`, `delete` and `disable`.

- The `disable` action changes the state of the entity and refresh the page.
- The `edit` action sends the user to a form, where the user can edit the entity.
- The `delete` action displays a confirm windows and if the users click `Yes` the entity is deleted.

What I am trying to do is to disable these buttons, while the server is handling the requests according to the action.

How can I do that? trying to use `$(".btn").attr("disabled", "disabled")` is not good enough because what happens if the user clicks on `delete` but then clicks on "No"? or when `edit` is being clicked but then the user decides to go back in history? in all these cases the buttons are still disabled.

Thanks.

Comment: are you making request with AJAX?

Comment: if yes, check this https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong jQuery function., try:

```
$('#myInputId').prop('disabled', 1);
```

Elements attributes such as disabled and readonly require the prop() method and a boolean to change the state.

Regarding your jQuery AJAX request and creating a UX notification for the user, you can use the beforeSend option when building out your AJAX request to either show an AJAX spinning GIF or insert a message into the DOM.

Hope that helps!

Comment: this does help a lot. however, what is missed is sort of a message/notification that the request is being processed. do you have an idea how i can do that using jquery/bootstrap/etc?

Comment: This can easily be done, if you add your AJAX code to your question I can highlight how to specifically integrate a notification.  Otherwise, I added a general suggestion to my answer above.

Comment: hey. i want to display a modal with a message saying the process is being handled but when i click on the `Edit` button, the form is not rendered in a new page. do you have an idea how i fix it? to add the code?

Comment: If you added the JavaScript code to the question it might help me answer more effectively.  Also, you want to generate a modal using Bootstrap or some other library?